# How to replace &lt; with < in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, xml, coldfusion, rss

I'm creating an XML document from database entries using ColdFusion and when the XML is created the `<` and `>` are in the format of `&lt;` and `&gt;`. So before it creates the XML is there a way to change the `&lt;` to a `<`?

Below is the code and an example of the output:

```
<cfquery name="messages" datasource="showcase_Uk">
     select * from t_items where pid = 2 and spid = 45
</cfquery>

<cfset myStruct = StructNew() />
<cfset mystruct.link = "http://showcase.com" />
<cfset myStruct.title = "Examples" />
<cfset mystruct.description = "Examples from UK Showcase" />
<cfset mystruct.pubDate = Now() />
<cfset mystruct.version = "rss_2.0" />
<cfset myStruct.item = ArrayNew(1) />

<cfloop query="messages">
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow] = StructNew()>
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid = structNew()>
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.isPermaLink="YES">
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.value = xmlFormat(#messages.id#)>
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].pubDate = createDate(year(#messages.uploadDate#), month(#messages.uploadDate#), day(#messages.uploadDate#))>
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].title = xmlFormat(#messages.name#)>
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description = StructNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description.value = xmlFormat(#messages.description#)>
</cfloop>


<cffeed action="create" name="#myStruct#" overwrite="true" xmlVar="myXML">

<cffile action="write" file="e:\domains\showcase.com\wwwroot\ukshowcasefeed.xml" nameconflict="overwrite" output="#XMLFormat(myXML)#">

 <cffile action="read" file="e:\domains\showcase.com\wwwroot\ukshowcasefeed.xml" variable="myfile">

 <cfoutput>#myfile#</cfoutput>
```

Then here is a screenshot of the code it produces:

[image: screen shot of output]

I've tried `ReplaceNoCase` and that doesn't change it at all. I believe it maybe something to do with Regex but I don't really know.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer:

Don't `XmlFormat()` when you write the file, that's what causes the double encoding you see.

---

Longer answer:

I recommend you use mapping to create your feed:

```
<cfquery name="messages" datasource="showcase_Uk">
  select
    id, uploadDate, name, description, 'yes' as isPermaLink
  from
    t_items
  where
    pid = 2 and spid = 45
</cfquery>

<cfset feedMeta = {
  version: "rss_2.0",
  title: "Examples",
  link: "http://showcase.com",
  publisheddate: Now(),
  description: "Examples from UK Showcase"
}>

<cfset feedMap = {
  title: "name",
  content: "description",
  publisheddate: "uploadDate",
  id: "id",
  idpermalink: "isPermaLink"
}>

<cffeed
  action="create"
  properties="#feedMeta#" columnMap="#feedMap#" query="#messages#"
  xmlvar="feedXml"
>

<cffile
  action="write"
  file="#ExpandPath('/ukshowcasefeed.xml')#" nameconflict="overwrite" charset="utf-8"
  output="#feedXml#"
>
```

Note the easy declarative approach to feed creation. No loops, no manual struct creation, only data-driven mapping of input to output.

Also note the `charset="utf-8"` on the `<cffile>`, that's essential if you don't want to run into encoding problems.

---

If you modify your query so that it has the correct column names right-away, then you don't even need the `feedMap` structure:

```
<cfquery name="messages" datasource="showcase_Uk">
  select
    id, 
    'yes' as idpermalink
    uploadDate as publisheddate,
    name as title,
    description as content 
  from
    t_items
  where
    pid = 2 and spid = 45
</cfquery>

<cffeed
  action="create"
  properties="#feedMeta#" query="#messages#"
  xmlvar="feedXml"
>
```

Comment: Seconded. You are specifically converting perfectly valid XML into escaped XML simply *because* you're passing it through `xmlFormat()`. If you don't want to do that... then just *don't*. On reflection, `xmlFormat()` is a really poorly-named function. It should be `encodeForCData()` or something

Comment: @AdamCameron In this case its use isn't even necessary. The problem I have with `XmlFormat()` is that it encourages thinking about XML as a string, which also was the basis of the mistake the OP made. XML is a data structure, just like a struct, it should be treated that way.